# Reading JSON in joint.js?

Tags: javascript, json, jointjs

I want joint.js library to read my JSON and display it as a chart...

```
var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
    el: $('#paper'),
    width: 600,
    height: 200,
    model: graph
});

var graph = new joint.dia.Graph;

jsonstring = '{"employees": [ { "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }, { "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" }, { "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" } ] }';

graph.fromJSON(JSON.parse(jsonstring));
```

Comment: I'm intrigued by a library that has a `fromJSON` method that doesn't accept JSON...

Comment: There is a reason for that. Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JSON#toJSON()_method and an example of another library: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON. JSON.stringify calls toJSON() of the object it stringifies recursively. toJSON() is supposed to return an object, not a string. Try: JSON.stringify({ toJSON: function() { return { foo: 'bar' } } }). fromJSON() is the opposite and therefore accepts an object, not a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the API for [joint.dia.Graph](http://www.jointjs.com/api#joint.dia.Graph):

> joint.dia.Graph is the model holding all the cells (elements and
>   links) of the diagram. It's a [Backbone
>   model](http://backbonejs.org/#Model). The collection of all the cells
>   is stored in the property cells.

So the expected JSON should be in this form: `{ cells: [] }`. Where `cells` is an array of both elements and links. Each element should have the form:

```
{ 
    id: <string>, 
    type: '<type of shape>', 
    attrs: { <attrs> }, 
    position: { x: <int>, y: <int> }, 
    angle: <deg>, 
    size: { width: <int>, height: <int> }, 
    z: <int>, 
    ... and some other, maybe custom, data properties 
}
```

Reference: [Using Server Data with JointJS](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jointjs/0O7KKQMnLeY/U4oU6_AcnV4J)

Comment: Just adding that you usually don't build the JSON by hand but by adding JointJS elements and links to the graph and then stringifying the graph with JSON.stringify(graph).